# Determining if 3 numbers in an array form a right triangle in javascript code

Tags: javascript

I am supposed to sort the array and determine the largest number (aka c).
Then, use the pythagorean theroem to determine if the numbers in the array can form a right triangle.
Also, when I run the code, I get an error saying anArray.sort is not a function.
I am new at Javascript and could really use some help. Thanks!

```js
//This is the start of my function

function isRightTriangle(anArray) {
    anArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b-a;
  });
    return anArray;
}

//This is the test case that was given.

function runTriangleTests() {
    console.log("Triangle Tests"):
    console.log(isRightTriangle(3, 4, 5) == true);
    console.log(isRightTriangle(13, 12, 5) == true);
    console.log(isRightTriangle(55, 23, 24) == false);
}
```

Comment: What part of that code is the part where you employ the Pythagorean theorem?

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling on an array. Do this instead:

```
console.log(isRightTriangle([3, 4, 5]) == true);
console.log(isRightTriangle([13, 12, 5]) == true);
console.log(isRightTriangle([55, 23, 24]) == false);
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: I'm not doing homeworks of OP. His question is about javascript: *I get an error saying anArray.sort is not a function.*

Comment: OK, but than, read again the Question's **title** : ***"Determining if 3 numbers in an array form a right triangle in javascript code"*** - therefore makes your answer much of a comment to OP's undevoted question - rather than a fully featured *here's your homework* Answer. Needless to say - it was not needed at all :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: So why don't you edit/delete the question? I am doing what I think helpful for the OP. When I have a partial answer, I post a comment. Here I think I have the full answer, so I post an answer. Because SO is not about mathematics. What part don't you agree with?

Comment: I don't agree with - that you answered only to the ***". Also, when I run the code, ..."*** part of the question - which could be rather a comment to OP's question. Do you agree with me, no?

Comment: (P.S: FYI), OP can delete it's own question (so it would not take 5 close-votes from high rep users like me) **only if** there's no provided answer. But there's one. Yours. Partially useful but does not fully addresses and answers OPs question - Rather it calls for upvotes - downvotes - uselessly for such a poor question. Hope you're getting my point clearer now.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Now it's clear. **So you downvote me so I delete my answer and you delete the question**... I am close to 1k reputation, you have more than 100k. You should know that helping in SO is not very rewarding: you get downvoted without reason by anonymous users and the OP often does not even care to accept the answer you took hours to write. There are meta posts about *rudeness* in SO. Thanks for not sanctionning the good wills.

Comment: Don't take downvoting too personal. Learn from it rather than sorrying. I've seen downvotes on SO answers only for three main reasons 1. Cause it's low-quality. 2. Cause of a misread (rare) 3. Cause of a rage/hate (even rarer) *you-downvoted-me-I'll-downvote-you* reasons which happen usually when the actual downvoter comments: ***"I downvoted you because you misse...etc"***. Frankly you cannot expect upvotes on such an answer, and I believe the downvoter will be much than happyer to remove the downvote after you improve your answer - (or you delete it).